# Unable to insert a converter into a facelets template component

Tags: jsf, myfaces, mojarra

When using MyFaces, I'm having trouble using ui:insert to insert a converter into a template component. The JSF implementation complains the the parent of my convertdateTime is not of the right type:

Parent not composite component or an instance of ValueHolder: org.primefaces.component.fieldset.Fieldset@6559fbd6

It seemingly then checks a Fieldset (which is a parent of a parent in my case)

```
<my:outputTextWithLabel id="creationdate" label="#{msg.common_datecreated}" value="#{bean.date}">
    <my2:convertDateTime/>
</my:outputTextWithLabel>
```

My outputTextWithLabel components looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">
    <ui:composition>
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{rendered or empty rendered}">
            <p:outputLabel for="#{id}" value="#{label}" />
            <div class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                <h:outputText id="#{id}" value="#{value}">
                    <ui:insert/>
                </h:outputText>
            </div>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

This code works fine with Mojarra...
So, just for clarity: isn't this supposed to work? Is Mojarra correct, or MyFaces? And what could be done here instead?

Comment: Note that for the same my:outputTextWithLabel, the same problem occurs with a standard f: converter.

Comment: Do you have version info about both Mojarra an MyFaces? And please edit your code and replace the converter. And making it into a [mcve] might help others reproduce.... cheers